# Add buttons to Windows Explorer to automate tasks

Tags: windows-explorer, script, automation

Is there a way to add a custom button to the Windows Explorer GUI so I can automate some tasks in folders, eg. to automatically create a new subfolder with the current date as its name?

The button could run a script or an external console app to perform the task.

I can relatively easily run the command line window in the current folder's path and then run a script there but I want to have a button to make this even easier.

Comment: Not the out-of-the-box explorer, no. You'd need a 3rd party application, or you'd have to decompile, edit and recompile the exiting explorer executable, which is non-trivial.

Comment: You can't add buttons, but you could use a keyboard-macro utility, such as AutoHotKey, to add keyboard shortcuts that do the job.

Comment: Easiest is to add "Open command window here" (https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-10/add-open-command-window-here-windows-10-context-menu) (or "Open PowerShell window here" to the context menu. On this PC, it activates with Ctrl-Shift-Right-Mouse-Button in Explorer.

Comment: A context menu entry under `HKCR\Directory\Bbackground\Shell` with the command: `powershell -Command "[void](md (Join-Path '%V' ((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))))"` would do the trick...